# jquery showing undefined data after search filter on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a short code after combing some codes on stackoverflow. I have made a select option which can be filtered by using input textbox. Now I am giving alert to option attribute (peak1) and it is showing peak1 attribute alert after clicking on option. But when I search and click option after searching then it doesn't show the value (it shows undefined). Please don't duplicate or delete this before giving the real working code. Please help me, I am sharing the code.

```html
<input type="text">
<select id="peaks" name="cars" size="5" style='border: 2px solid green;'>
 <option peak1='10'>Copper</option>
 <option peak1='40'>Silver</option>
 <option peak1='70'>Gold</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var select = this;
    var options = [];
    $(select).find('option').each(function() {
      options.push({
        value: $(this).val(),
        text: $(this).text()
      });
    });
    $(select).data('options', options);

    $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
      var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
      var search = $.trim($(this).val());
      var regex = new RegExp(search, "gi");

      $.each(options, function(i) {
        var option = options[i];
        if (option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
          $(select).append(
            $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
          );
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

$(function() {
  $('select').filterByText($('input'));
});

$('#peaks').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).find(':selected').attr('peak1')
  alert(value);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<input type="text">
<select id="peaks" name="cars" size="5" style='border: 2px solid green;'>
 <option peak1='10'>Copper</option>
 <option peak1='40'>Silver</option>
 <option peak1='70'>Gold</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var select = this;
    var options = [];
    $(select).find('option').each(function() {
      options.push({
        value: $(this).val(),
        text: $(this).text(),
        peak1: $(this).attr('peak1'),
      });
    });
    $(select).data('options', options);

    $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
      var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
      var search = $.trim($(this).val());
      var regex = new RegExp(search, "gi");

      $.each(options, function(i) {
        var option = options[i];
        if (option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
          $(select).append(
            $('<option>').text(option.text).attr('peak1', option.peak1)
          );
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

$(function() {
  $('select').filterByText($('input'));
});

$('#peaks').on('click', function() {
  var value = $(this).find(':selected').attr('peak1')
  alert(value);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `value` attribute for `option`...

```
<select id="peaks" name="cars" size="5" style='border: 2px solid green;'>
 <option value='10'>Copper</option>
 <option value='40'>Silver</option>
 <option value='70'>Gold</option>
</select>
```

... and update the JavaScript everything works fine.

```
var value = $(this).find(':selected').attr('value')
```

The problem seems to be that you're using custom naming for the `value` attribute, or you change that or find a way to have `peak1` appended as an attribute:

```
$(select).append(
    $('<option>').text(option.text).attr('peak1', option.value)
);
```

**Update**: After further analysis you were also adding the text value of each option to the value attribute as you can see by checking options array.
You have to do this too:

```
$(select).find('option').each(function() {
    options.push({
      value: $(this).attr('peak1'),
      text: $(this).text()
    });
  });
```

Comment: Yes sir, but I want to use many peak attribute like peak1 peak2, peak3 and so on. So I can not change peak1 to value because then I need peak2, peak3... attributes. Please help if in append I can append with peak1 value so that it will work

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code. See the `append` I did.

Comment: Sir, when I replace the append function then after search it is showing option value in alert not the peak1 value in alert? Can you please give me full working code where it shows peak1 value after searching

Comment: Sir, it is workign by adding ".attr('peak1', option.peak1)" and adding "peak1: $(this).attr('peak1')," in option.push function. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Sir, I have posted a working solution which is working after searching. But there is a little problem that after search it is showing peak1 attribute on double click, not on single click. I don't know why it is happening

Comment: That's because the first click is what is effectively marking the `option` with `selected`.

Comment: Can you please suggest me something to make it possible in single click sir?